# How to do variable type casting in php?

Tags: php

PHP, as most of us know, has weak typing. But what about those who don't require this.
My problem is, here I have this code:

```
$total_price=0;
while(some condition)
{
    //1st iteration
    $total=0;
    $total = number_format(2450.0000*1,4);
    echo $total;//output-like 2,450.0000
    $total_price +=number_format($total,4);
    //2nd iteration
    $total=0;
    $total = number_format(1600.0000*2,4);
    echo $total;//output-like 3,200.0000
    $total_price +=number_format($total,4);
}
```

then `echo $total_price;` is `5` ....how?
apart from `number_format()` here I want addition and multiplication of `xxxx.0000,xxxx.0001` strictly have `4` decimal places e.g. `0.0000 + 0.0000 = 0.0000` not `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number is a number. A formatted number is a string. Numbers are for calculating and strings are for displaying. As soon as you try to do a calculation on a string, PHP will try to convert it back to a number again.

You should do the calculation first and only format it when you output it.

Answer (score 3):

This has absolutely nothing to do with <strike>"weak"</strike> dynamic typing. Pretty much any language, regardless of type system, will behave this way.

Numeric ***values*** do not have "strictly four decimal places". There's no difference between `2450` and `2450.0000000` and `2450.00`. It's all exactly the same value. You cannot do math with a strict number of decimal places.

Moreover, float values are not precise; if you require precision, you'll want to use [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Either way, you ***format*** the number of decimal places upon output, when you `echo` your number. Before that the number of decimal places do not matter. See [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) and [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf).